# Spring boot app with Vaadin UI constantly refreshing screen

Tags: java, spring-boot, vaadin14

I have a boot app that I am adding some crud screens to.  I decided to use Vaadin and it seems to work great until I deploy it to a multi-nodal production environment.
Once in the prod environment the screens constantly refresh for no apparent reason. For example there is a grid in one screen that when a row is clicked a dialog pops up that shows item details. but as soon as the dialog pops up the page refreshes numerous times.

This forum thread here https://vaadin.com/forum/thread/17586129/routerlayout-causing-page-refresh is an example of the same layout I am using and describes a very similar issue.

I have a base abstract class that extends VerticalLayout and all of the concrete classes extend this base abstract class. Each concrete class defines its own route and use a common layout class.

I have reached out on gitter, vaadin forum and opened a bug in github but no one from Vaadin want to respond to anything as far as I can tell.

Here are the versions of everything I am using:
Vaadin Flow version: 14
Java version: 12.0.1+12
OS version: Mac 10.14.5
Browser version: Fire Fox 70.0.1, Chrome 78.0.3904.97

Code snippets from my implementation:
Main View

```
@Slf4j
@RoutePrefix("v1/crud")
@Theme(value = Material.class, variant = Material.DARK)
public class MainView extends Div implements RouterLayout {
private H1 h1 = new H1("Vaadin Crud UI");
private HorizontalLayout header = new HorizontalLayout(h1);
private Div content = new Div();
private ApplicationContext context;

@Inject
public MainView(ApplicationContext context) {
    this.context = context;
    setSizeFull();
    h1.setWidthFull();
    content.setWidthFull();
    header.setWidthFull();
    header.setAlignItems(FlexComponent.Alignment.CENTER);
    VerticalLayout navigationBar = new VerticalLayout();
    navigationBar.setWidth("25%");

    navigationBar.add(createNavigationButton("Home", VaadinIcon.HOME, ReportTab.class));
    navigationBar.add(createNavigationButton("Batch Search", VaadinIcon.SEARCH, BatchSearchTab.class));
    ... a bunch more buttons
    HorizontalLayout layout = new HorizontalLayout(navigationBar, content);
    layout.setWidthFull();
    VerticalLayout page = new VerticalLayout(header, layout);
    page.setWidthFull();
    add(page);
}

@Override
public void showRouterLayoutContent(HasElement hasElement) {
    if (hasElement != null) {
        Element newElement = hasElement.getElement();
        if (newElement != null) {
            content.removeAll();
            content.getElement().appendChild(newElement);
        }
    }
}

private Button createNavigationButton(String caption, VaadinIcon icon, Class<? extends BaseEditor> editor) {
    Button button = new Button(caption, icon.create());
    button.addClickListener(event -> UI.getCurrent().navigate(editor));
    button.addThemeVariants(ButtonVariant.MATERIAL_CONTAINED);
    button.getStyle().set("background-color", "#00819D");
    button.setWidthFull();
    return button;
}

}
```

Base Component:

```
@Slf4j
@Data
@SpringComponent
@UIScope
public abstract class BaseEditor<P, B> extends VerticalLayout {

private final RememberMeService rememberMe;
private final P businessProcess;
protected Binder<B> binder;
protected Dialog editDialog = new Dialog();
protected Button save = new Button("Save", VaadinIcon.CHECK.create());
protected Button close = new Button("Close", VaadinIcon.EXIT.create());
protected Button delete = new Button("Delete", VaadinIcon.TRASH.create());
protected B bean;

private ChangeHandler changeHandler;
private boolean proceed = true;

public BaseEditor(P businessProcess, RememberMeService rememberMe) {
    this.rememberMe = rememberMe;
    this.businessProcess = businessProcess;
    save.addClickListener(e -> save());
    delete.addClickListener(e -> delete());
}

public abstract void delete();

public abstract void save();

protected abstract Component getContent();

protected void edit(B e) {
    bean = e;
    editDialog.open();
    getBinder().setBean(e);
}

protected void initEditorPanel(Component... components) {
    HorizontalLayout actions = new HorizontalLayout(save, close, delete);
    VerticalLayout data = new VerticalLayout(components);
    data.add(actions);
    editDialog.removeAll();
    editDialog.add(data);
    getBinder().bindInstanceFields(this);
    close.addClickListener(e -> editDialog.close());
}

public interface ChangeHandler {
    void onChange();
}

void setChangeHandler(ChangeHandler h) {
    changeHandler = h;
}

void errorDialog(String message) {
    final Button close = new Button("Close", VaadinIcon.CLOSE.create());
    H3 h3 = new H3(message);
    final Dialog errorDialog = new Dialog(h3, close);
    errorDialog.open();
    close.addClickListener(e -> errorDialog.close());
}

BaseEditor filter(Predicate<B> predicate) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(predicate);
    proceed = predicate.test(bean);
    return this;
}

void buttonConsumer(Consumer<B> consumer) {
    if (!proceed) {
        proceed = true;
        return;
    }
    try {
        consumer.accept(bean);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        errorDialog(e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        editDialog.close();
        getChangeHandler().onChange();
    }
}

void either(Consumer<B> whenTrue, Consumer<B> whenFalse) {
    try {
        if (proceed) {
            whenTrue.accept(bean);
        } else {
            whenFalse.accept(bean);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        errorDialog(e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        proceed = true;
        editDialog.close();
        getChangeHandler().onChange();
    }
}
}
```

Concrete Component:

```
@Slf4j
@Route(value = "search/batch", layout = MainView.class)
public class BatchSearchTab extends BaseEditor<BatchService, Batch> {
private TextField searchField1;
private TextField searchField2;

public BatchSearchTab(BatchService businessProcess, RememberMeService rememberMe) {
    super(businessProcess, rememberMe);
    binder = new Binder<>(Batch.class);
    save.setIcon(VaadinIcon.REPLY.create());
    save.setText("Replay");
    delete.setIcon(VaadinIcon.CLOSE.create());
    delete.setText("Cancel");
    getContent();
}

@Override
public void delete() {
    buttonConsumer(b -> getBusinessProcess().cancelBatch(b.getBatchId(), b.getUserAgent()));
}

@Override
public void save() {
    filter(b -> b.isReplayable()).buttonConsumer(b -> getBusinessProcess().buildAndSendFile((getBean())));
}

@Override
public void edit(Batch batch) {
    HorizontalLayout actions = new HorizontalLayout();
    H2 h2 = new H2();
    if (batch.isReplayable()) {
        h2.setText("Would you like to replay the following.");
        actions.add(save, delete, close);
    } else {
        h2.setText("This record is not eligible for replay.");
        actions.add(close);
    }

    Label batchId = new Label("Correlation Id: " + batch.getBatchId());
    Label txnCount = new Label("Transaction Count: " + batch.getTotalTxns());
    Label txnAmount = new Label("Total: " + batch.getTotalBatchAmount());
    VerticalLayout data = new VerticalLayout(h2, batchId, txnCount, txnAmount, actions);
    data.add(actions);
    editDialog.removeAll();
    editDialog.add(data);
    close.addClickListener(e -> editDialog.close());
    editDialog.open();
    getBinder().setBean(batch);
}

@Override
protected Component getContent() {
    final H2 h2 = new H2("Locate Batches");
    searchField1 = new TextField("Batch Code");
    searchField2 = new TextField("User Agent");
    searchField2.addKeyPressListener(Key.ENTER, e -> keyPressListener());
    Button searchBtn = new Button("Search", VaadinIcon.SEARCH.create());
    HorizontalLayout search = new HorizontalLayout(searchField1, searchField2);
    searchBtn.addClickListener(e -> {
        search(searchField1.getValue(), searchField2.getValue());
    });
    add(h2, search, searchBtn);
    return this;
}

private void search(String code, String userAgent) {
    log.info("Searching {} and {}", code, userAgent);
    List<Batch> batches =
        getBusinessProcess().getBatchesForUserAgent(code, userAgent, 60);
    log.info("Found {} batches", batches.size());
    if (batches.size() > 0) {
        buildGrid(batches, "BatchId", "totalTxns", "totalBatchAmount", "status");
    } else {
        errorDialog("No Records found for criteria");
    }
}

private void keyPressListener() {
    String code = StringUtils.isNotBlank(searchField1.getValue()) ? searchField1.getValue() : null;
    if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(searchField2.getValue())) {
        search(code, searchField2.getValue());
    }
}

private void buildGrid(Collection<Batch> records, String... columns) {
    Component result;
    if (records.size() == 0) {
        result = new Label("NO REPORT DATA AVAILABLE.");
    } else {
        final Grid<Batch> grid = new Grid<>(Batch.class);
        grid.setHeightByRows(records.size() < 10);
        grid.setColumns(columns);
        grid.setItems(records);
        grid.setWidthFull();
        grid.asSingleSelect().addValueChangeListener(l -> Optional.ofNullable(l.getValue()).ifPresent(this::edit));
        result = grid;
    }
    if (getComponentCount() < 3) {
        add(result);
    } else {
        replace(getComponentAt(2), result);
    }
}

private void loadData(String code, String userAgent) {
    if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(code)) {
        search(null, userAgent);
    } else {
        search(code, userAgent);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Looks like it is an issue related to not using sticky sessions 
https://vaadin.com/blog/microservices-high-availability

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Disclaimer**: some further fact finding happended via IRC

The answer to the question is related to OP running multiple instances of the application behind an round robin load ballancer.  The clients hit random servers and therefor had no session running there.

The solution to this is having a shared session store and ideally have the load ballancer dispatch on existing session, so "hot" backend servers get hit.